# How do I make an element in html not an entire line long

Tags: javascript, html, function, paragraph, content-length

So what I'm trying to make is a paragraph in HTML and then when you click on it it would do a certain action, for example:

```
<p id='hello'>Hello</p>

<script>
hello.onclick = function() {
 console.log("clicked!");
}
</script>
```

the only problem is that when I click next to the text, it still detects it as a click, I want the click ratio to be the length of the paragraph's text. What's the best way I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `inline` element instead of `p` like below -

```
<span id='hello'>Hello</span>
```

Because `p` is block element and no matter where your contents gets over in the line it will takes the space of whole line.

For more in details refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp#:%7E:text=Compared%20to%20display%3A%20inline%20%2C%20the,display%3A%20inline%20they%20are%20not.)

Comment: If it solved your issue, mark it as accepted to close this question and upvote if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I write an example, I think this helps you
you can see the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nimaamr/7efjn29x/5/)

```
  <buttom onclick="clickMe()">click me please</buttom>
  <div>
    <p id="write"></p>
  </div>

<script>
     function clickMe() {
        let getELementP = document.getElementById("write");
        getELementP.innerHTML = "writeHere";
      }
</script>
```